# How to use hash in search? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of gas views, the user chooses one of the gases key as shown below. So for example, the user can choose Carbon Dioxide [CO2]. Then, if the user wants to search for the gas, they go the search page. However, user usually don't write the name and just write the element, so in the search model below, I tried to only compare the value and the searched input, but I t didn't work. Is there something I can do?

gas and search has different controller.
gas controller

```
@Gases = {'Carbon Dioxide [CO2]' => "CO2", .......}
```

gas view

```
<%= f.select :gas, @Gases.keys%>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work
Search model

```
sensors = sensors.where("lower(gas.value(key)) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{gas}%")
```

Comment: What is data type of gas?

Comment: are you using PostgreSQL and **hstore** datatype?

Comment: I am using SQL.